# How to set up git user for group-writeable repositories and SSH access?

Tags: ssh, git, file-permissions

I am setting up a Git server on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.  I need the server to support both the SSH and HTTP protocols.

So far I've followed the instructions in [the Git Book](http://www.git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server) to get my server to support the SSH protocol.

To support the HTTP protocol, I'm hooking [pushover](https://github.com/substack/pushover) into my existing web server.  Since the web server is running as a different user, though, it wouldn't be able to write to the main repositories, which are owned by the "git" user.  So I added my web server user to the "git" group, and did a `chmod -R g+w /home/git` and got the HTTP protocol to work.  However, by doing this I inadvertently broke SSH access to the repos, since OpenSSH does not allow a user's home directory to be group-writeable.

There are a couple things I've thought of to solve this issue.

1. Change the global SSH configuration options, either by setting a custom `AuthorizedKeysFile` location or by setting `StrictModes no`.  I don't want to do either of these things because the changes affect my other non-git SSH users.
2. Remove group write privileges from the git user's home directory, and then write a script that manually adds group write privileges to new repositories.  This would probably work but it just doesn't seem like a very elegant solution.

Any suggestions for how to structure my file system to allow for group-writeable git repositories while at the same time maintaining SSH access?

Comment: How about moving the repositories out of the home directory?

Comment: The main problem with moving the repos out of the home directory is that it messes up existing SSH checkouts that I have.